# Domain in IIS not accessible to users outside of the VPS

Tags: iis

I have two domains in IIS `cms.example.com` and `oldexample.com`.

I want to turn `oldexample.com` into `api.example.com`

My API is hosted on this sub domain. I already added the right DNS settings weeks ago (same as cms but then changed the name to api).

`cms.example.com` is accessible and `oldexample.com` is as well. But outside of the VPS environment `api.example.com` is not reachable.

When I navigate to this URL on my phone or laptop I get an 404. 
When I navigate to this URL through the browser in remote desktop it shows the response I expect.

Because the DNS has been like this for weeks I know the issue can't be there (waiting for it to update for example).

What is going wrong here and how can I resolve this issue?

I set both the HTTP and HTTPS bindings to port 80.

`oldexample.com` and `api.example.com` are bound on the same project.

Comment: If you don't know what is site binding, run a report and learn it https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 404 (aka "Not found") means that your browser *is* reaching a webserver somewhere, but the requested page is not found.

Given your situation, I would proceed in the following steps:

1. check if the domain `api.example.com` resolves to the right public IP address
2. check that the port 80 on the public IP address is actually reacheable from the Internet
3. check if the website responding is actually the one you expect, not some default website

I would recommend doing checks from a PC connected to the Internet, not using remote desktop on the server itself.

Off course, I'm assuming `example.com` is being used as an example in your question and the real domain is a valid one, that you actually control!

For the first check, on a linux box I would do `dig api.example.com` on a terminal. On a windows box, I would do `nslookup api.example.com`. In the DNS response, the IP address should be the public IP address of your VPS server. If it doesn't, you have misconfigured the DNS.

For the second check, on a linux box I would do `telnet api.example.com 80`. Same thing on a Windows box (in recent versions on Windows, telnet is not installed by default). I would expect to see `Connected to api.example.com`. If it says `Trying <ip-address-here>` and nothing else, than the port 80 is not reacheable from the Internet. Maybe your VPS provider blocks ports by default and you need to explicitly go and open them from some management console or something similar.

If the above checks where ok, you need to work on your IIS configuration.

Comment: Thanks, above check works fine. I get the IP and things I was expecting. But why would (by URL) the website show up on the VPS and not on remote locations? It is not like I am referring to localhost, or is it in the background?
EDIT: Telnet doesn't work on both domains. `408 Request Timeout`.

Comment: If telnet times out, you problably need to check with your VPS provider how to open port 80 to the Internet. They probably have a guide or a tutorial to do so.

Comment: From a security standpoint, it is a good practice to keep all ports closed by default and then let you explicitly open the ones you actually need.